# When selected index changed in combo box, how to add this new index to another text box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

I have two controls in my web form. One is combo box control, and the other is text box. What I want to do is when user selects another item in combo box, the new item is added to text box and shown to user automatically.

For example:
1. When user select '001' item in combo box, text box shows '001' in text area.
2. When user select '002' item in combo box, text box shows like this: '001','002'

Here is my code:

```
class webform : System.Web.UI.Page{

    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    protected void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Todos: Add the selection of combo box to text box2. 
        this.localsb.Append(this.ComboBox1.Text);
        this.localsb.Append(",");
        this.Text2.Text = this.localsb.ToString();
    }

......
}
```

Here is my front end code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PCA_Form.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.PCA_Form" Culture="auto" meta:resourcekey="PageResource1" UICulture="auto" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>PCA_Form</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #Text1 {
            width: 147px;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }

        #form1 {
            height: 718px;
            width: 963px;
        }

        .auto-style1 {
            font-size: large;
        }

        #Checkbox1 {
            width: 112px;
        }

        #Select1 {
            width: 162px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.ComboBox1').on('blur', function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    var initial = $('#Text2').val();
                    var checkbox = $(this).text();
                    $('#Text2').val(initial + ',' + checkbox).change();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <div style="height: 51px; width: 906px;" aria-atomic="False" draggable="auto">
            <span class="auto-style1">New Price</span>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Text1"
                runat="server"
                class="Text"
                onkeypress="if (event.keyCode!=46 && (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode >57)) event.returnValue = false;"
                TextMode ="MultiLine">
            </asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="auto-style1">Item Number</span>
            <ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1"
                TextMode="MultiLine"
                runat="server"
                AutoPostBack="True"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                DataTextField="Code"
                DataValueField="Code"
                Style="display: inline;"
                AutoCompleteMode="Suggest"
                DropDownStyle="DropDown"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">

            </ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
            &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button1"
                Text="submit"
                OnClick="SubmitButton_Click"
                runat="server" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Excel" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <asp:TextBox ID="Text2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

        </div>

        <div style="height: 466px; width: 943px; margin-top: 35px">
            <span class="auto-style1">&nbsp;<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;Integrated Security=True" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT [Code] FROM [Item]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="PCADataGrid" runat="server" Width="938px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="PCADataGrid_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns ="true">
            </asp:GridView>
            </span>
        </div>

    </form>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

</body>
</html>
```

In combo box tag, I trigger a function called ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged() when user changes selection in this box.

Comment: Why not do this with javascript?

Comment: Was writing an answer doing just that as you wrote this.

Comment: My friend @JamesBlond , because I am not very familiar with JS.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that is indeed possible.  However, your approach will require an *Update Panel* and all the agony that follows if you intend to avoid the lovely screen-flicker from those pesky *Postback's*.  I would recommend doing this client side with JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.Checkbox').on('blur', function() {
          if($(this).prop('checked')) {
               var initial = $('#txtField').val();
               var checkbox = $(this).text();
               $('#txtField').val(initial + ', ' + checkbox).change();
          }          
     });
});
```

That is a bit crude and rough, but it should meet your needs.  This will avoid the issues your bound to introduce by using the *Asp.Net Page Life Cycle*.  Hopefully this points you in good direction.

As I said above your approach will:

- *Require* Postback or Update Panel

**Problem:**

1. Postback - Screen will flicker, plus can make managing View State quite difficult.
2. Update Panel - A pain to work with, also will hinder performance.  As each 'Postback' becomes an Ajax call of the page.  Which is stored in memory, so every Postback becomes stored in memory during the life-cycle.  So it isn't very efficient.

**Update:**

---

You asked a question about:

- `.Checkbox`
- `#txtField`

On your front-end, in source code your elements are created like:

```
<asp:TextBox 
     id="txtField" runat="server"
     placeholder="Initial Content..." />
```

There are more you can place on the control, but to answer your question they correlate to the *Id* or *Class* name for the given element your manipulating.  An `Id` can only be bound to a single element, where a class can be used on several elements.  For example-

```
<asp:Checkbox
     id="chkField" runat="server"
     CssClass="Checkbox" />
```

So in this instance the `.` is an anchor on this case, `.Checkbox`.  The next would be `#` which is to anchor to the `Id`, `#chkField`.  So when you use JavaScript they use the `$('.Checkbox')` or `$('#chkField')` as the *Selector* to elements on your page.  Does that clarify for you?

Comment: Thanks Greg. As I am not very familiar with JS, please tell me where should I put this code.

Comment: If you lookup using JavaScript in Asp.Net you'll see.  It goes in your front end code for .aspx under `script`.

Comment: Well,Greg. Would you please tell me what do '.Checkbox' and '#txtField' stand for in code above?

Comment: Thanks you Greg. Still cannot understand this jQuery code. I didn't learn this before. And I re-edit my code and paste my front code. I try to add what you said in <stript>, but cannot work. Please help me more. Thanks again.

Comment: In order for the JavaScript to work as intended, you'll need to remove all those server events like `SelectedIndexChanged`.  You also may need to trigger a `change` event by calling `.change();` at the end of the JavaScript.  Also your `SqlDataSource` doesn't need to be in a span, it is hidden. There is quite a bit that would need to change mostly as I can see the inexperience in the code you've written.  Which will take time to get the hang of properly.  If I have time I'll write a fiddle that will do it for you as a demo.

Comment: Thanks Greg. It is my first time coding in ASP.NET. Need help from experience coders!